# All rows displayed when trying to display rows that contain a string

Tags: php, sqlite

I have some code where I want it to only show rows where there is a certain string in a column. I have a column called "Tags" where it has tags in this format "tag1, tag2" Etc. I want to have links so people can only show products with a certain tag. This is where I run into problems. I can't get it to show rows with certain tags, it shows every row.

```
<?php
try {
    //open the database
    $db  = new PDO('sqlite:prodDb.sqlite');
    $tag = $_POST['tag'];
    if (isset($tag)) {
        $result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM Products WHERE instr(Tags, $tag) > 0');
    } else {
        $result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM Products ');
    }

    //now output the data to a simple html table...
    $result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM Products');
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        print "" . $row['Id'] . "<br />";
        print "" . $row['Name'] . "<br />";
        $tags = explode(', ', $row['Tags']);
        foreach ($tags as $tag) {
            print "Tag: " . $tag . "<br />";
        }
        print "" . $row['Link'] . "<br />";
        print "" . $row['Screenshot'] . "<br />";
        print "" . $row['Download'] . "<br />";
    }


    // close the database connection
    $db = NULL;
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    print 'Exception : ' . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Any ideas where I went wrong?

Comment: I don't see how the query could work at all. You need quotes around `$tag` in the query. But it would be better to use a prepated query and `bindParam`, rather than interpolating a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the `$db->query` line here:

```
//now output the data to a simple html table...
$result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM Products');
```

You're discarding the results from the query that matched the tag, and using this query that returns all products.

In the query with the tag, you have a syntax error, because you need quotes around the string. It would be better to use a prepared query:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM Products WHERE INSTR(Tags, :tag)');
$stmt->execute(array(':tag' => $tag));
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Also, if you have all the tags in a single column, you have a poor table design. You should normalize your data by moving the tags into a separate table, with one row per tag for each product.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize I left that in. It didn't help though. Somehow it's still not working. Now when I use ?tag=tagname in the url it shows nothing. I think something is wrong with the query. I guess I need to try other queries.

Comment: I've added the fix to your query that searches for the tag

Comment: That'll do it. Thanks. I've stayed away from databases for too long. Need to use them more to get things going.

Probably not a good idea to code when super tired either. Now to make pagination and have the output look how I need it to look. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

It probably doesn't work because here:

```
//now output the data to a simple html table...
$result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM Products');
```

You are simply selecting all products and ignoring the previous query/filter.